# Can't update user with PUT Request in Angular 2

Tags: angular, put

I am building an Angular 2 app and I have created an API that is online and that lets me update a user that has name, email and about fields. 
I tested it with Rest Easy and I could update any user but when I try to update it from Angular 2 nothing changes in database, what I am trying to do is the following:

```
updateUser(user: User) {
    let url = 'http://example.com/api/user/update' + user.user_id;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(user)); // this prints out in console correctly

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http
        .put(url, JSON.stringify(user), { headers: headers })
        .map(res => res.json());
}
```

The full **user.service.ts** file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from "@angular/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        console.log('user service initialized');
    }


    // this works perfectly
    getUsers() {
        return this.http.get('http://example.com/api/users')
            .map(res => res.json());
    }

    // this also works perfectly
    getUser(userId: number) {
        return this.http.get('http://example.com/api/user/' + userId)
            .map(res => res.json());
    }

    // this is where nothing happens, only prints in console the object
    // but no errors are displayed
    updateUser(user: User) {
        let url = 'http://henriquealho.esy.es/public/api/user/update/' + user.user_id;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(user)); // this prints out in console correctly

        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return this.http
            .put(url, JSON.stringify(user), { headers: headers })
            .map(res => res.json());
    }

}

interface User {
    user_id: number,
    name: string,
    email: string,
    about: string
}
```

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to send data via HTTP client from Angular don't use `stringify`, Angular will handle all of the required processes to send your data. Just use the following:

`.put(url, user, { headers: headers })`

PS. Angular sets the `content-type` header of your `post` or `put` requests to `application/json` if you're sending json data, due to a content type detection. See the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/bebedfed24d6fbfa492e97f071e1d1b41e411280/packages/http/src/static_request.ts#L103).

Edit (from comments):

You have to subscribe to a created observable to run your request. Use `this.userServie.updateUser(user).subscribe()` to run your request. And maybe consider a `take(1)` after your `map` call to complete it after 1 request is done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer cyrix but that didn't help, I still can't update my user :/

Comment: Did you check via developer tools what your request from your angular application looks like? If you do, could you add a screenshot of the request data to your question and the corresponding code of your backend method which handles the update.

Comment: Yes I did check via developer tools and the strange is that nothing gets printed for the PUT request. As I mentioned, the backend is working with rest easy but I will leave a link to an image of that method.

Comment: Here is the Codeshare: https://codeshare.io/5Q86M7
To build the API I am using PHP Slim Framework.

Comment: If the request doesn't get executed, are you subscribing to your updateUser anywhere? Because if you're creating an Observable (which `http.put` does) without subscribing to it, it won't get executed, try to add an `take(1)`  after your `.map` call or subscribe to it when you want to update.

Comment: var user = {
            user_id: this.userId,
            name: this.name,
            email: this.email,
            about: this.about
        }
        this.userService.updateUser(user);

I am calling the update from the service in this way, I am not subscribing anything, how may I do that? The take(1) gives an error of not found, should I import anything?

Comment: Try `.map(res => res.json()).take(1)` and if `take` is unkown import it with `import "rxjs/add/operator/take"`

Comment: The import solves the error but nothing gets printed on the Network log using chrome dev tools

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139057/discussion-between-cyrix-and-henrique-alho).

Comment: Calling the update method with this.userService.updateUser(user).subscribe(); solved my problem, thank you cyrix one more time! :)