# updating user details MEAN stack

Tags: node.js, angular, express, angular5

Im stuck at updating a user profile, I've tried the solution on [Can't update user with PUT Request in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43022673/cant-update-user-with-put-request-in-angular-2) but it doesn't seem to work, perhaps its starting at me in the face but I can't seem to figure it out.

On my auth.service.ts I have this

```
updateDetails(id) {
   let headers = new Headers();
   this.loadToken();
   headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken);
   headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   return this.http.put('http://localhost:3000/api/admin/' + id, this.user { headers: headers })
  .map(res => res.json());
}
```

Then on client-edit.component.ts I have

```
updateUser(id) {
   this.authService.updateDetails(id).subscribe(res => {
   this.router.navigate(['/client-details', id]);
   }, (err) => {
  console.log(err);
})
```

the user.js file has

```
router.put('/admin/:id', function(req, res, next) {
   User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, function (err, post) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      res.json(post);
   });
});
```

And finally the client-edit.component.html has

```
<form (ngSubmit)="updateUser(user._id)"
......
...
```

Can anyone see where I've gone wrong, I don't get any errors in the console, I can see in the terminal that the put requests seem to be going through, but when I check it doesn't update at all.

Any insight to this I would really appreciate it.

Kind Regards,
- P

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 return this.http.put('http://localhost:3000/api/admin/' + id, JSON.stringify(this.user), { headers: headers })
```

Comment: unfortunately that did not work =[  
thanks for the response!

Comment: I don't get any error, it just doesn't update to the backend correctly, sorry for the delay in replying